# Using node.js client-sessions without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, server

I'm trying to get [client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions#usage) to work without using express but I'm not sure if I'm porting the example correctly.

`var sessionOptions = { cookieName: 'mySession',
  secret: 'blargadeeblargblarg',
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 };
  var session = new SESSION(request, response, {}, sessionOptions);`

When I run this client-sessions complains

> cannot set up sessions without a secret or encryptionKey/signatureKey pair

Does client-sessions need express to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions:

> client-sessions is connect middleware

So while it might not need `express`, it needs `connect` to work as per the docs.

The specific error though, is because you aren't using the library correctly. You need to configure a session before using it.

```
var sessions = require("client-sessions");

var session = sessions({
  cookieName: 'mySession',
  secret: 'blargadeeblargblarg', 
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5
});

// then inside route handler..
session(req, res, function(){ console.log('done!'); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how the Connect/Express syntax translated to pure node.