# Error: cannot set up sessions without a secret or encryptionKey/signatureKey pair

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to get client-sessions to work on Ubuntu.  However, whenever I run `nodejs app.js` I get this error.  I'm trying to figure out what's going on but I can't find what's going on.  I read the client-sessions information on their NPM/Github sites but I can't figure out what's going on.  Can anyone help me or lead me to the right place?

The entire error:

```
/home/tom/cookiestut/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:548
    throw new Error("cannot set up sessions without a secret "+
    ^

Error: cannot set up sessions without a secret or encryptionKey/signatureKey pair
    at clientSessionFactory (/home/tom/cookiestut/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:548:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tom/cookiestut/app.js:34:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576768/using-node-js-client-sessions-without-express

Comment: Please, add some code of your application: how do you import the library, initialize it. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `client-sessions` you must set either `secret` or both `encryptionKey` and `signatureKey`, as [recommended in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions#usage

```
var sessions = require("client-sessions");
app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'mySession', // cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object 
  secret: 'blargadeeblargblarg', // should be a large unguessable string 
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms 
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 // if expiresIn < activeDuration, the session will be extended by activeDuration milliseconds 
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.mySession.seenyou) {
    res.setHeader('X-Seen-You', 'true');
  } else {
    // setting a property will automatically cause a Set-Cookie response 
    // to be sent 
    req.mySession.seenyou = true;
    res.setHeader('X-Seen-You', 'false');
  }
});
```

The [code of `lib/client-sessions.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions/blob/d0c20af3b0ed7750c68d3ae67819dfe203fa3d60/lib/client-sessions.js) checks that secrets or two keys are initialized in `clientSessionFactory` method:

https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions/blob/d0c20af3b0ed7750c68d3ae67819dfe203fa3d60/lib/client-sessions.js#L542

```
  if (!(opts.secret || (opts.encryptionKey && opts.signatureKey))) {
    throw new Error("cannot set up sessions without a secret "+
                    "or encryptionKey/signatureKey pair");
  }
```

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/using-secure-client-side-sessions-to-build-simple-and-scalable-node-js-applications-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-3/ page says how to set `secret` - by using some long random string ([for example, combine several strings from the site random.org](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=20&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new)):

```
app.use(clientSessions({
  secret: '0GBlJZ9EKBt2Zbi2flRPvztczCewBxXK' // set this to a long random string!
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you're getting it's self-explanatory. If you follow the stack trace you can see that in the following path and line:

`/home/tom/cookiestut/app.js:34:9` you're missing to set up the secret to your cookie session configuration. Probably you have it configured as an environment variable and you forgot to define it.

Add a secret manually to the cookie set up